# Why Key up is not being called up in this case?

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML

My question is that why the onkey up function is not being called up in this case ??

```
<div id="addNewAddress">
<input id="city" type="text" class="autosuggest" placeholder="City">
</div>


$("#city").keyup(function()
{
    alert('city'); 
    var city = $(this).val();
    var state  = $("#state").val();

    if(city!=''&&city.length>2)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url+'/OrderSnacks/oms/autosuggestcity?city='+city+'&state='+state,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
            success: function (responsesss)
            {
                $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
                    source: responsesss
                });
            },
            error: function (e)
            {
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I even tried it using

```
$("#city").on("keyup", function(event){

});
```

Comment: have you wrapped it in script tag?

Comment: Looks like the script tag will do it. +1 simply because you don't really deserve that downvote

Comment: Are there any other scripts affecting `#city`?  Do you see any other errors in your console?  Are you *sure* that the function is not being called?  Maybe the `if` is false, or there's an error?

Comment: @Doctus: My guess is he actually has a script tag in his real page, and he just forgot to add it when he copied & pasted.

Comment: @hellaFont: HTML5 lets you do `<input>` without closing it (I think).

Comment: @hellaFont you don't need to do that anymore for singular tags

Comment: But if i put inside the $(function(){ this will increase the page load time .

Comment: @PreethiJain: No it won't.  Where did you read that?  You need `$(function(){})` to make sure the DOM is ready (and the elements exist) before you bind to them.  So, try adding `$(function(){})`, that sounds like your issue.

Comment: this will be called at the page load time know so it takes time to load know

Comment: @hellaFont: You **never** needed to do that in an HTML file.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder with XHTML I believe you did

Comment: @Doctus: Right. And if you're using XHTML, you'll know you're using XHTML (the hairshirt is the first clue). I'll bet you *money* the OP isn't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yet it would go in a HTML file...

Comment: @RocketHazmat: *"HTML5 lets you do `<input>` without closing it (I think):"* You think right. :-) As did HTML4.1, HTML4, and HTML3.2. It's an XHTML thing.

Comment: @Doctus: No, it would go in an XHTML file.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's simply not true

Comment: @Doctus: A file that contains XHTML is an XHTML file. A file that contains HTML is an HTML file. A file that contains RTF is an RTF file. A file that contains CSS is a CSS file. And so on. (I think we're getting very off-point here, though.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Granted, that is a good way of putting it - I concede my point. However I don't think it's that black and white, because you'd save xhtml in a .html file and use a DOCTYPE to tell the browser how to parse it. In the same way I could have a .php file that serves CSS and has adjusted headers

Comment: @Doctus: True enough. The relationship between XHTML (the serialization), HTML (the serialization), and HTML (the thing defining the elements, attributes, etc.) isn't quite as simple as my note above would suggest. :-)

Comment: Sorry for the interruption ,but my question was side tracked , Could anybody please tell me why putting under $(function() will not increase the page load time ,as i am seeing this is getting called during page start up .

Comment: @PreethiJain: Of course it gets called during page start up.  It's a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){})`.  It won't slow it down, because when it runs, your page is *already* downloaded.  It's gotta run at some point to be able to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put it on $(document).ready(function(){:

```
<div id="addNewAddress">
<input id="city" type="text" class="autosuggest" placeholder="City">
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#city").keyup(function()
    {
        alert('city'); 
        var city = $(this).val();
        var state  = $("#state").val();

        if(city!=''&&city.length>2)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: url+'/OrderSnacks/oms/autosuggestcity?city='+city+'&state='+state,
                jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                cache: true,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: false,
                success: function (responsesss)
                {
                    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
                        source: responsesss
                    });
                },
                error: function (e)
                {
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```